# "error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'COORD' requested"

Tags: c++

I get this solitary error while trying to compile the following code in code::blocks.
The error is occurring 8 lines down.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD pos = (40, 3);
SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, pos);
cout << "O" << endl;
Sleep(500);

for (int tossIt = 1; tossIt <= 3; tossIt++)
{
    while (pos.Y <= 20)
    {
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, pos);
        cout << "|" << endl;
        pos.Y++;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, pos);
        cout << "O" << endl;
        Sleep(100);
    }
    while (pos.Y > 3)
    {
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, pos);
        cout << " " << endl;
        pos.Y--;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, pos);
        cout << "O" << endl;
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
COORD pos = (40, 3);
```

This should be:

```
COORD pos = {40, 3};
```

Note the use of {} instead of ().

Answer (score 1):

```
COORD pos = (40, 3); // (40,3) is comma expression, 3 is "retrurned"
COORD pos(40, 3); // you intent?
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I needed to change the ( to {.